# retrieve async ads insights results from FB ads API with pagination

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am using [facebook-python-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk) to make async calls for FB insights API as [described](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/v2.10).

```
params = {
    "time_increment": 1,
    "level": "ad",
    "date_preset": "last_28d",
    "breakdowns": "hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone",
    "limit": 1000
}

job = AdAccount("id").get_insights_async(params=params)
result_cursor = wait_for_async_job(job)
results = [item for item in result_cursor]

def wait_for_async_job(job):
    for _ in range(TIMEOUT):
        time.sleep(1)
        job = job.remote_read()
        status = job[AdReportRun.Field.async_status]
        if status == "Job Completed":
            return job.get_result()
```

So the job to retrieve insights for last_28d finishes in a few minutes, however, the pagination over the results can take up to an hour!

Is it the right way to paginate over an async job?

Comment: people who copy paste this code, you can replace the deprecated `remote_read` with `api_get`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am posting the answer so it can help other developers that had the same issue.

modify:

```
return job.get_result()
```

to:

```
return job.get_result(params={"limit": 1000})
```

This will paginate over the results in jumps of 1000 and not the default which is 25.

The above change saved us 30 minutes of run.

Comment: This actually helps for synchronous requests as well! I had an issue with `get_ad_sets()` caused by pagination. It took forever to complete, and most often than not I got `request limit reached`. Once I added 'limit': 1000 to `params`, the request ended after a few seconds! Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem and this code works for me

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebook_business.adobjects.adreportrun import AdReportRun
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
import time

campaign = Campaign(<CAMPAIGN_ID>)

params = {
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.campaign,
}
async_job = campaign.get_insights(params=params, is_async=True)
async_job.api_get()
while while async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_status]!= 'Job Completed':
     time.sleep(1)
     async_job.api_get()
time.sleep(1)
print(async_job.get_result())
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your code? That would increase the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```py
return job.get_result(params={"limit": 1000})
```

with

```py
list(async_job.get_result())
```

to get always all responses. `get_result()`
is an iterator.

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677205/2227743) rather than a new answer.