# Facebook Insights API - getting error code 1 with subcode 99

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

We are retrieving Insights data via the Facebook Marketing API. We are using the Python "facebookads" module for this. I was downloading historic data in the past for all of our accounts which was working perfectly fine. Since 2 weeks or so I am getting this error:

> 2018-06-01 16:01:57 - (DEBUG) - urllib3.connectionpool - https://graph.facebook.com:443 "GET /v2.11/act_nnnn/insights?access_token=&appsecret_proof=&time_range=%7B%22since%22%3A%222018-05-08%22%2C%22until%22%3A%222018-05-08%22%7D&level=ad&breakdowns=%5B%22impression_device%22%5D&filtering=%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22spend%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22GREATER_THAN%22%2C%22value%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D&limit=5000&fields=account_id%2Ccampaign_id%2Ccampaign_name%2Cadset_id%2Cadset_name%2Cad_id%2Cad_name%2Cimpressions%2Cclicks%2Creach%2Cspend%2Caccount_currency%2Cactions%2Caction_values%2Ctotal_actions%2Ctotal_action_value HTTP/1.1" 500 77
>
> 2018-06-01 16:01:57 - (DEBUG) - FacebookAdsDownloader - An exception occurred:
>
> Message: Call was not successful
>
> Method:  GET
>
> Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_nnnn/insights
>
> Params:  {'time_range': '{"since":"2018-05-08","until":"2018-05-08"}', 'level': 'ad', 'breakdowns': '["impression_device"]', 'filtering': '[{"field":"spend","operator":"GREATER_THAN","value":"0"}]', 'limit': 5000, 'fields': 'account_id,campaign_id,campaign_name,adset_id,adset_name,ad_id,ad_name,impressions,clicks,reach,spend,account_currency,actions,action_values,total_actions,total_action_value'}
>
> Status:  500
>
> Response:
>      {
>        "error": {
>          "code": 1,
>          "message": "An unknown error occurred",
>          "error_subcode": 99
>        }
>      }

Anyone has an idea, why I get this error? This very same request was working already. I have retried the same request over and over.

Comment: This occurs intermittently on queries for https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_nnnn/campaigns , as well. Retry with no changes and it succeeds.

Comment: @J_H I have retried so many times, always the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shireesh Asthana from Facebook Developer team mentions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/215595309233224/) that too much data is requested and asynchronous requests have to be used.
Example can be found here: [retrieve async ads insights results from FB ads API with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675916/retrieve-async-ads-insights-results-from-fb-ads-api-with-pagination)